# how to get aggregated logs from running Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a continuous running Spark Application which reads msgs from Kafka and does some processing. Is there a way to get aggregated "Application Logs" ?

AFAIK, log aggregation will happen only when SparkContext is destroyed.

Comment: are you running in YARN ?  you want the logs in YARN ?

Comment: Yes Arun. here is my command - /usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --supervise --driver-memory 20G --executor-memory 20G --driver-class-path=/home/jvadisela/spark/guava-18.0.jar:/home/jay/spark/jackson-core-2.4.5.jar  --class com.collectivei.datarollup.entry.Startup  /home/jay/spark/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: is it a streaming application ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using spark streaming for Kafka integration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried standard YARN command for logs?

yarn logs -applicationId some-id